# Ubuntu 13.10 first install new user

Tags: 13.10

probably been answered but cannot find it.  Just installed for the first time today with no previous experience.  On trying to update get message authentication fails.  My Ubuntu one account can be accessed with the password.  Not clear what the problem is or what steps I have missed.

thanks

Comment: could you post the screen shots of the fails message ?

Comment: When you were installing Ubuntu and were asked for a user name and password - **that password** is what you need to enter when asked to authorize when updating. Is that what you are entering?  UbuntuOne account passwords are not tied to machine account passwords.

Comment: thanks but do not know how to cut an paste as cannot add any software to set up machine.  Will try a reinstall

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get update (you need admin rights)

man sudo (shows the manualpage for sudo, this works for almost any command)

Comment: thank you but am new so still trying to work put how to run sudo. However if it requires the authentication I will still be unable to progress

Comment: You need to open a terminal window and enter the command.

Answer (score 0):

- To update you needs to type : `sudo apt-get update`. (It will update
  your package  list).
- To install new package type : `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`
  (it will install specific package. eg `sudo apt-get install vlc` to
  install vlc.)
- If you want to update your system ie. to update all installed package
  type: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

You can use `tab` for auto-completion.